# How to read and append Iptables in docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, iptables

I am unable to figure out how to read iptables in my docker container. I was handed over this by someone who I am not in contact with hence I am unable to figure this out. Any help would mean a lot please.

Comment: What you really want to achieve?

Comment: The usual answer is "you don't": Docker normally fully manages the container networking environment, most containers don't have `ip` or `iptables` installed as tools, and normally Linux capabilities prevent the container from trying to modify the container-specific firewall.